There was a problem building the apk and appbundle projects
I tried using the flutter_tflite: ^1.0.1 package to build a real-time object detection app. Everything worked fine when I tested it on the emulator. However, when I tried to build it into an APK and app bundle, the following error occurred:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_tflite:verifyReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.VerifyLibraryResourcesTask$Action
   > Android resource linking failed
     ERROR: /Users/baka/Documents/Application/llenn/myappku/build/flutter_tflite/intermediates/merged_res/release/mergeReleaseResources/values/values.xml:194: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.



app/build.gradle

plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    // The Flutter Gradle Plugin must be applied after the Android and Kotlin Gradle plugins.
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.myappku"
    compileSdk = 35
    ndkVersion = flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias = "sipisang"
            keyPassword = "Bakachi2024"
            storeFile = file("/Users/baka/Documents/aplikasi/keystore/sipisang.jks")
            storePassword =  "Bakachi2024"
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId = "com.example.myappku"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://flutter.dev/to/review-gradle-config.
        minSdk = 23
        targetSdk = flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode = flutter.versionCode
        versionName = flutter.versionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.

            minifyEnabled true
            // useProguard true
            shrinkResources true

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro' 
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress 'tflite'
        noCompress 'lite'
    }
}

flutter {
    source = "../.."
}





gradle-wrapper.properties
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.3-all.zip



settings.gradle
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }()

    includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "8.1.4" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "2.0.21" apply false
}

include ":app"




android/build.gradle
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = "../build"
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(":app")
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}




flutter doctor

What can I try next?

I found out that you're working on a Flutter project as an assignment. If that is so, I suggest building your app as a debug for the meantime only. Not for release; is it your assignment's requirements/instructions?

Or, if you still want to build your project using that setup. I'll reproduce it; just wait for a moment. Kindly edit your question to include your gradle-wrapper.properties, settings.gradle, and android/build.gradle file configurations. I'll also leave you a note, the issue is related to your gradle. I have to reproduce it first to test which version of gradle is compatible with your flutter_tflite package.

Kindly provide your flutter doctor generated output as well.

I have updated it.

What edition of Android Studio you're using?

On my updated answer, you will see that the version of gradle is based on Android Studio's version. It seems you're using distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.9-all.zip which is not specified on the matrix.

Android Studio Version: "Ladybug | 2024.2.1 Patch 2", Build Number:"Build #AI-242.23339.11.2421.12550806", Runtime Version: "21.0.3+-79915917-b509.11 aarch64"

Then, what should I do?

In the meantime, leave it as it is. I updated my answer again, which mentioned how I resolved your case. If it says the issue persists, just let me know.

Good luck with your assignment! Keep it up!

Tip: adding assignment deadline notes to your Stack Overflow question is a good way to get downvotes. We're aiming for documentation-quality material here, in order to help future engineers, so this sort of thing is discouraged.

In android/app/build.gradle, add the following setting in the android block.
aaptOptions {
    noCompress 'tflite'
    noCompress 'lite'
}

So you have to configure your app/build.gradle into:
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    // The Flutter Gradle Plugin must be applied after the Android and Kotlin Gradle plugins.
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.myappku"
    compileSdk = flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion = "27.0.12077973"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId = "com.example.myappku"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://flutter.dev/to/review-gradle-config.
        minSdk = flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdk = flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode = flutter.versionCode
        versionName = flutter.versionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias = keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword = keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile = keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword = keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile(
                    'proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress 'tflite'
        noCompress 'lite'
    }
}

flutter {
    source = "../.."
}

Then rebuild your project.
Please consider this version matrix based on the Android Studio version:

Here's the source.
Update
Here's what I perform to resolve the exception:

Execution failed for task ':app:minifyReleaseWithR8'

Add this to your proguard-rules.pro file:
# Ignore Play Core dynamic features if not used
-dontwarn com.google.android.play.core.**
-dontwarn io.flutter.embedding.engine.deferredcomponents.**

# Prevent R8 from removing these classes (if referenced)
-keep class com.google.android.play.core.** { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.embedding.engine.deferredcomponents.** { *; }

Before building a release build of an APK, I perform these commands first:
flutter clean
flutter pub get
cd android
./gradlew build

Here's what I've got:

PS C:\path_to_your_app\android> flutter build apk --split-per-abi
Changing current working directory to: C:\path_to_your_app
Font asset "MaterialIcons-Regular.otf" was tree-shaken, reducing it
from 1645184 to 1384 bytes (99.9% reduction). Tree-shaking can be
disabled by providing the --no-tree-shake-icons flag when building
your app. Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
21.4s √ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk (11.2MB) √
Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-arm64-v8a-release.apk (13.8MB)
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-x86_64-release.apk (14.9MB)

ADDITIONALLY
Add first your proguard-rules.pro file, if it is not yet added to your project.
In your Android Studio, right-click on the app directory, select New > File, then type proguard-rules.pro to add the file.

Here's my build configuration:
proguard-rules.pro file
#Flutter Wrapper
-keep class io.flutter.app.** { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugin.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.util.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.view.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugins.**  { *; }

# Ignore Play Core dynamic features if not used
-dontwarn com.google.android.play.core.**
-dontwarn io.flutter.embedding.engine.deferredcomponents.**

# Prevent R8 from removing these classes (if referenced)
-keep class com.google.android.play.core.** { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.embedding.engine.deferredcomponents.** { *; }

gradle-wrapper.properties file
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.3-all.zip

settings.gradle file
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }()

    includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "8.1.4" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "2.0.21" apply false
}

include ":app"

app/build.gradle file
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    // The Flutter Gradle Plugin must be applied after the Android and Kotlin Gradle plugins.
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.flutter_build_ref"
    compileSdk = 35 // flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion = flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias = "dummyKeyAlias"
            keyPassword = "dummypw"
            storeFile = file("C:/your_predefined_path/dummyKeyStore/keystore.jks")
            storePassword = "dummypw"
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId = "com.example.flutter_build_ref"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://flutter.dev/to/review-gradle-config.
        minSdk =  23 // flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdk = flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode = flutter.versionCode
        versionName = flutter.versionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.

            minifyEnabled true
            // useProguard true
            shrinkResources true

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro' 
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress 'tflite'
        noCompress 'lite'
    }
}

flutter {
    source = "../.."
}

NOTE: For testing purposes, I've decided to create a dummy key store.
I am using Android Studio Koala | 2024.1.1, but you can test my build in your updated Android Studio version (only if introduce other exception).
To answer the question,

Does the version of Java also have an impact?

Here's the reference:
Java

Kotlin

Source: Compatibility Matrix.
Note: Based on my observation while dealing with gradle, kotlin, and java compatibilities. You have to understand what is the meaning of the exception logs coming from your app, before you adjust your certain tools version. Don't forget to perform cleaning of caches while you are having struggles with your build. Sometimes, it introduces conflict with the cache build. Restarting your Android Studio IDE isn't always necessary.
Tips: always read official tools documentation from which you are dealing with.
Here's the supporting reference to somehow help you to deal with build issues.
I hope it helps!

Have you tried flutter clean and clean caches?

I've already done it, but it's still the same.

Execution failed for task ':flutter_tflite:verifyReleaseResources'. and
Execution failed for task ':app:minifyReleaseWithR8'.


Kindly provide the file configuration I've mentioned in the comment section of your question. It would also be necessary for the others to see which dependencies you're currently using while I'm working on it to help you as well.

I have followed the guidance you provided, but a new error appeared: "An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application']".

I have updated the gradle-wrapper.properties file.

You can check my latest updates on my answer; I've updated it just now.

Excuse me, I would like to ask: I have searched for the "proguard-rules.pro" file in my project but couldn't find it.

Since you said your app works fine in debug mode. Sorry for the confusion; you can now revert your changes to your original state. I hope it will work now.

Okay, I will include it in my answer.

You can now check. Good luck!

I have followed the instructions you provided, but a new issue has appeared: 'Execution failed for task ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.

what should I do?

The only I can say is, you're using incompatible gradle for your project and environment setup. You can now downgrade your distributionUrl on which it is compatible with. Please be careful. Read some official documentation like this one.

You can follow my configurations setup gradle 8.3. After configuring. Perform flutter clean flutter pub get. If necessary, File > Invalidate Caches...

Does the version of Java also have an impact?

s this the correct command to build an APK?
'flutter build apk --split-per-abi'

After I read the documentation of that command, I found out that it is useful when you are planning to publish your app's APK to third-party sites. However, as you mentioned in your question, you are working with flutter project for your assignment. So I suspected it is because that's your assignment's requirements

If not, read the official documentation of building Flutter app for a simple setup of your project. If you want to submit an Android app in an APK build. Simple setup will do. You don't need to use proguard-rules.pro and its related configurations.

You have to decide which you are more comfortable to work with.

As its current state, I advice you to fix your current issue first. For you to find out what it could provide for you. Don't be hesitated to try it out first.
